# Rails text_area size

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `text_area` inside a `fields_for`, which is inside a `form_for`.

```
<%= day_form.text_area :hatch %>
```

Is it possible to change the size of the `text_area`? For example: `day_form.text_area size: 5`.

Answer (score 159, accepted):

You could either go with:

```
<%= day_form.text_area :hatch, cols: 30, rows: 10 %>
```

or you can specify both with the size attribute:

```
<%= day_form.text_area :hatch, size: "30x10" %>
```

Comment: this does not work now is there a rails 3.1 solution which is different from this one?

Comment: I didn't see this mentioned, but you can also write it like so:    <%= f.text_area :text, :size => "60%x5%" %> *This is in Rails 4.0.0*

Comment: I had to change f.text_field to f.text_area.

Answer (score 11):

For responsiveness I like to make the text area width 100% :

`<%= f.text_area :description, rows: 10, style: 'width:100%;' %>`

Answer (score 3):

As text area has both row and column you have to specify both

```
<%= text_area(:application, :notes, cols: 40, rows: 15, class: 'myclass') %>
```

For text field can use

```
<%= text_field(:application, :name, size: 20) %>
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-text_area